# How to trigger command prompt activity running in the background using keyboard?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd, command-prompt

For example I have a python file running. The cmd window is minimized, and I want to take input. I want to bind the input to some shortcut key. Like if I normally want **enter** key as the input with cmd in the **foreground**, pressing **Shift+S** with cmd in the **background** should do the same thing for me.

Here's the segment of the code where the execution continues when **Enter** is pressed.

```
base = path
while True:
    video = random.choice(os.listdir(path))
    path += video
    p = subprocess.Popen(["C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe","file:///"+path])
    raw_input("Shuffle...")
    p.terminate()
    path = base
```

But for that, the cmd window should be in the foreground. I want to use a shortcut key in place of **Enter** input with cmd in background.

I hope I am clear on this.

Comment: This is likely platform dependent. Generally, you could bind the shortcut to a program (that will be desktop dependent) that signals or otherwise communicates with the running program. Maybe the running program keeps its pid in a well known place or listens on a named pipe. Desktops may already have message passing mechanisms (eg dbus) that you could use. So, lots of options.

Comment: @serk I have edited the question. See the code above.

Comment: @tdelaney Do I have to write some additonal code for it, or is it a different process?